# How to make the entire MediaWiki site Dofollow?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am the administrator of a MediaWiki site and I want to make the entire site dofollow. Generally, all MediaWiki Sites are nofollow.

Answer (score 2):

Set [`$wgNoFollowLinks`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgNoFollowLinks) to `false` in LocalSettings.php.